# Estimating limit of an integral

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

> Suppose the limit
>
> $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+x^2)^n}$$
>
> exists and is larger than $\frac12$. Then
>
> A. $\frac12<L<2$
>
> B. $2<L<3$
>
> C. $3<L<4$
>
> D. $L\ge4$

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKurT.png)

I was trying solving this problem. I tried expressing the integral as a sum, but could not do anything further.

Comment: @user170231 Really too kind!

Comment: When you say you tried expressing the integral as a sum, do you mean a Riemann sum, or do you mean an infinite series?

Comment: I mean an infinite series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This integral is actually equal to
$$
\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \frac{dx}{\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{n} \right)^n}
$$
which tends to
$$
\int_{0}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.
$$